# Unable to deploy to the microservices application on pcf-dev using jenkins cloufoundry plugin?

Tags: jenkins, cloud-foundry

I have installed cloudfoundry plugin for Jenkins. In the Jenkins job i provided all the details and when i click on test connection it fails with below error.can someone help me please?

### Unknown Exception

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error getting /info from Cloud Controller
at org.cloudfoundry.client.lib.rest.CloudControllerClientFactory.getInfoMap(CloudControllerClientFactory.java:106)

Caused by:org.cloudfoundry.client.lib.org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('<' (code 60)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')
at [Source: java.io.StringReader@18601e6; line: 1, column: 2]
```

---

Comment: It looks like the cloud foundry plugin is not able to pull the CF installation information. Can you execute "cf curl v2/info" from your jenkins workspace? Also validate your manifest.yml for format errors.

Comment: I am getting below error.                                                                            c:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace>cf curl v2/info
'cf' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: You need an installation of the cloudfoundry cli. See here: https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cli

Comment: conclusion: 1) I gave the wrong URL in target value of the Jenkins cloud foundry plugin settings in post build action i.e instead of "api.system.nprd-pcf.company.net"; i gave "apps.system.nprd-pcf.company.net"; 2)I installed cf cli. But, am still confused if the issue is only with the wrong target value or even by not installing the cf cli?

Answer (score 1):

You are probably getting back an HTML page, instead of a JSON file. Since the first character parsed is a `<` character.

You may have configured a wrong cloudcontroller API endpoint within your Jenkins installation. For pcfdev it should be `api.local.pcfdev.io`.

Comment: i dint install cf cli, i will first install that and try. In jenkins documents, its no where mentioned to have a pre-requisite for cloudfoundry plugin

Comment: Hi, I  am able to use cf login and push my application. I even added those commands in "execute windows batch commands" and it was successful. But when i run with cloud-foundry plugin , the same error repeats. this is the target value am giving in Jenkins plugin   "https://apps.system.nprd-pcf.mycompany.net"

Comment: yes, i gave wrong target value instead of api i misplaced the word with "apps", now its working thanks.

Comment: conclusion: 1) I gave the wrong URL in target value of the Jenkins cloud foundry plugin settings in post build action i.e instead of "api.system.nprd-pcf.company.net"; i gave "apps.system.nprd-pcf.company.net"; 2)I installed cf cli. But, am still confused if the issue is only with the wrong target value or even by not installing the cf cli?

Answer (score 0):

The error message refers to the likely configuration syntax error:

```
Unexpected character ('<' (code 60))
```

Validate your manifest.yml using any online validator (like http://www.yamllint.com/)

You can also verify your access/credentials by logging into your Jenkins Organisation/Workspace (as set on the plugin configuration page) using

cf login -o YourJenkinsOrg -s YourJenkinsSpace

and then running

cf curl "v2/info"

Comment: Do you really need a manifest file for configuration of CloudFoundry Jenkins Plugin? The question does not ask about pushing an application!

Comment: i dint install cf cli, i will first install that and try. In jenkins documents, its no where mentioned to have a pre-requisite for cloudfoundry plugin

Comment: @user152468 You are correct and your answer is more likely to cover the root cause of the issue observed. Thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: @AnatolyKern : Hi, I have tested the manifest, it said its a valid one. I tried those commands from jenkins workspace, they are also working i.e am able to use cf and login and and push my application. I even added those commands in "execute windows batch commands" and it was successful. But when i run with cloudfoundry plugin , the same error repeats

Comment: Sadhan you need to run

    cf api

per https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/running/cf-api-endpoint.html and set correct api endpoint in jenkins plugin configuraiton per @user152468 answer.

Comment: yes, i gave wrong target value instead of api i misplaced the word with "apps", now its working thanks.

Comment: conclusion: 1) I gave the wrong URL in target value of the Jenkins cloud foundry plugin settings in post build action i.e instead of "https://api.system.nprd-pcf.company.net" i gave "https://apps.system.nprd-pcf.company.net"  2)I installed cf cli.               But, am still confused if the issue is only with the wrong target value or even by not installing the cf cli?

Comment: in order to deploy 50 microservices is it better to have 50 Jenkins jobs? and 50 times we need to use cloud-foundry plugin to push the apps? can some one suggest me the strategy? there may be a situation where i may deploy only one or 10 or 50